# Repartitioning Linux for Windows

Tags: windows

I have Linux installed on my computer, but I need Windows for some things that I can't do with Wine, so I wanted to use a dual boot. I haven't done this before, but I just installed Linux so I don't have any files to risk if I screw up anyways. When I open GParted I have 3 partitions that were set up when I installed:

- sda1    fat32        512Mb
- sda2    ext4         693Gb
- sda3    linux-swap   4.97

I thought I should reduce the ext4 partition so I could make one for Windows, but I can't resize it, the minimum and maximum options it gives are the same. I can't seem to do anything at all with the other two partitions either. What am I supposed to do to let me make a new partition?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize sda2 partition while it's in use. You need to boot your computer using a live USB or DVD Ubuntu, and then start Partition Manager GParted to shrink sda2 to the right, creating necessary free space (20gb?) to create a new partition (ntfs) for Windows.

Beware that your grub2 bootloader will be replaced with Windows boot manager and you won't be able to boot into Ubuntu immediately. You can only do this after restoring grub2 bootloader using some tool like boot repair disk (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd) after which you can have an option to boot into Windows as well as Ubuntu.

Comment: 50 GB is a safer approach.  Since Windows uses pagefile.sys and after needed items for Windows, I am left with 20-25 GB free.

Comment: Ok that makes sense that I wouldn't be able to resize while using the partitions. So after I shrink the sda2, I should make a completely new partition for Windows instead of getting rid of the other ones? Im sure I need sda1 since thats boot, but im not entirely sure what the swap partition is. Is it fine to leave it that size?

Comment: If sda1 is your current /boot partition that has to go at least when installing Windows because it will definitely require using it. The new partition to be created between currant sda1 and sda2 will be the main location for Windows installation though. So you should better keep all the other partitions to be able to continue using your current system in addition to Windows. Your current swap partition is the Linux version of Windows page file and you should better keep it as well.

Comment: And finally I can recommend making a backup of your disk before such a radical operation, for example using **clonezilla**.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you want a 3 Partition Drive.  2 OS and 1 Data.  The first thing you need to do is understand one thing.  Windows and Linux has programs that only work with those OS' natively on the partition the OS is installed on.

So now that is covered. You need to back your data up on the Partition you are wanting the Data Drive to be on.  This will ensure something bad happens, you can know you have that data else where.

Next you need to restart your PC.  Use a LiveUSB of either Windows or Ubuntu.  Enter Gparted/Fdisk depending on your USB.  Now, in order to use this fully you need to shrink your Ubuntu part to 50 GB.  Then  make an NTFS Part thats also 50 GB.  Finally make another part of the leftover space in NTFS.  Please note to keep the other two partitions.

Finally install Windows.  After windows is installed, enter your UEFI Boot Manger in your BIOS and make Ubuntu the first choice to boot to.

After you boot into Ubuntu, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to access a Terminal to enter

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

At which point you can boot into Windows if needed.
This data Partition makes it where you can access items from Linux just in case you need them from use in Windows, since Windows cannot see the Z: drive Ubuntu calls home.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have known to use an NTFS partition. However, Im a bit confused by your recommendation. Your saying to shrink my sda2 to 50GB, then make a new 50GB in addition where I'll put windows. Then you say make another part of the space NTFS, is that just with the remaining 593GB I would have? Also you say to keep the other TWO partitions, but I currently have 3 that were set up when I installed. Do I only need 2 of those?

Comment: Sorry keep all three parts shrink the linux one make two more.